# verilog always, begin and end evaluation

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to learn Verilog using Pong P. Chu's book.  I have a question about how an always block is evaluated and implemented.  A style in the authors code is confusing me.

In this example he codes an FSM with two output registers 'y1' and 'y2'. The part I'm confused about is in the NEXT STATE LOGIC AND OUTPUT LOGIC always block, where after the begin statement and `always@*` y1 and y0 are set to 0.  I seems that regardless of state, y1 and y0 will toggle to 0 on every clock cycle and signal change.  According to state diagram in the book reg y1 should be equal to 1 while in state 0 or 1.

So does y1 toggle to 0 every clock cycle then back to what ever its value at the present state??  I assume that's not the case and that I'm just confused about how the block is evaluated. Can someone explain what that part of the code is doing.  I'm lost. Thanks

```
module fsm_eg_2_seg
    (
     input wire clk, reset, a, b,
     output reg y0, y1
    );

    //STATE DECLARATION
    localparam [1:0]    s0 =2'b00, 
                    s1=2'b01, 
                    s2=2'b10;

    // SIGNAL DECLARATION
    reg [1:0] state_reg, state_next ;

    //STATE REGISTER
    always @(posedge clk, posedge reset)
        if (reset)
            state_reg <= s0;
        else
            state_reg <= state_next;

    //NEXT STATE LOGIC AND OUTPUT LOGIC
    always @*
    begin
        state_next = state_reg; // default next state: the same
        y1 = 1'b0;              // default output:  0
        y0 = 1'b0;              // default output:  0
        case (state_reg)
            s0:  begin
                y1 = 1'b1;
                if (a)
                    if(b)
                        begin
                            state_next = s2;
                            y0 = 1'b1;
                        end
                    else
                        state_next = s1;
                end
            s1:  begin
                    y1 = 1'b1;
                    if (a) 
                        state_next = s0;
                    end
            s2: state_next = s0;
            default: state_next = s0;
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression

```
always @* begin : name_of_my_combinational_logic_block
    // code
end
```

describes combinational logic. Typically the clk and rst signals are not read from inside of this type of always block, so they don't appear in the sensitivity list like wisemonkey says. It is best practice to use @* for the sensitivity lists of combinational logic so that you don't forget to include a signal, which would infer some memory and it would no longer be combinational logic.

Inside a combinational logic block, you should use what are called **blocking assignments**. These look like regular variable assignments in most programming languages and use a single equals. The value that you assign to a variable (a reg) inside of a combinational logic block happens **immediately** with respect to other statements and expressions in that same combinational logic block, but does not propagate outside of this combinational logic block until you reach the end. The always block must reach the end before any changes are seen outside of the block. Paul S is right that you want to always assign *something* to your variables whenever the always block is executed, otherwise you will infer memory.

Comment: I originally meant this comment back at you.  But I think I'm getting it. Not to beat a dead horse, but to be sure I understand this type of always block: It infers combination logic? So will case statement inside the always will infers a circuit that "executes" continuously? Or does the case statement only "execute" when ever an input in the always block changes?

Comment: The hardware that is inferred is combinational logic and executes continuously. However the only time the outputs of combinational logic change are when the inputs change, so in practice having the always execute only when an input changes is perfectly fine. Unfortunately, Verilog is able to describe things that are not hardware so folks like us need to be extra careful. In my opinion, Pong P. Chu does a great job not showing all of the useless features of Verilog and concentrates on what you need to actually make hardware: combinational logic blocks and sequential logic blocks.

Comment: Yeah.  Chu's book has been pretty good.  I like the coding style and it does a pretty good job of explaining the circuits, but it's not a book on the Verilog language.  His example codes in the book have worked pretty well.  Now I'm trying to understand why they work!  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @FrankDejay: This is wrong and/or misleading on a number of levels - you shouldn't accept it as an answer, as it will just confuse anyone else looking this up. Do a search on 'setting default values for combinatorial logic' to find out what's going on here.

Answer (score 4):

Have to say I disagree with aqua. What he (and wisemonkey) says about `@*` is right, but the rest is wrong.

Those two lines have nothing to do with an idle state. Those statements are there as good coding practise. They ensure that those two outputs are always assigned to when that always block is evaluated. Let's see why this is important:

- Imagine that those two statements aren't there.
- Next suppose that `state_reg = S0`, and `a = b = 0`
- As we evaluate the always block, we enter the case statement, s0 half, and assign 1 to `y1`
- `a` is zero so we don't enter the if statement, and we drop out of the case, and end the block

At the end of the block `y1 == 1` and `y0 == ...` erm, hang on what does `y0` get? I guess it has to keep it's old value. It didn't get a new one.

That means it's possible `y0` has to remember it's value from one cycle to the next. That would mean it needs to have some kind of memory involved, like a register or a latch. In this case it would be a latch as it's written in a style that sometimes drives the output and sometimes holds it.

...but we don't want that. `y1` and `y0` were meant to be simple wires. Therefore we must make sure each of them are always assigned to, no matter what the state or inputs are. We could do that by having assignments in all the branches of the logic, but that becomes a lot of work. Alternatively we can have a default assignment which we later override if necessary.

The reason these statements don't introduce `y1` going to `0` in `s0` or `s1` is because everything that happens inside an always block happens with no time passing. No time passes between the `0` being assigned at the top and the `1` in `s0` or `s1`. All that's visible is the final state.

You'll note the code does exactly the same thing with the state variable. It has a default assignment that the next state is the current state, and then overrides that it the correct conditions are met.

Nice clean state machine. Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: not to beat a dead horse, but to be sure I understand this type of always block:  It infers combination logic? So will case statement inside the **always** will infers a circuit that "executes" continuously? Or does the case statement only "execute" when ever an input in the always block changes?

Comment: Also BTW y0 and y1 are declared

Comment: Also BTW the declaration for y1 and y0 are **output reg y0, y1**.  Does that change anything about your explanation?  OH.  Also does ** always @* ** mean only declared inputs that are in the always block, or does it also refer to any signal that is in the always block regardless of if it was declared an input, output, or reg?  Thanks.

Comment: @FrankDejay: It infers combinational logic because a variables are assigned to in all cases (so no latches) and we're not using an event like a clock edge to say when the code should run (so no registers). The whole always block (not just the case statement) executes whenever any of it's input's change (the @*), which is equivalent to it executing continuously. Read it as "Always, when * changes, do this"

Comment: @FrankDejay: The declaration of y0 and y1 isn't really important in this case, and don't be fooled by the 'reg'. It doesn't mean y0 and y1 will be registers. Whether they are registers or not is completely down to how the code is written which assigns values to them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a poor example of an FSM. I'm not surprised that you are confused. The way I understand it, an `always` block is scheduled to run only when the inputs in its sensitivity list change.

So for the first `always` block, it is scheduled to run every clock transition from 0 to 1, and reset is asynchronous.

The second always block has the `@*` notation, which basically creates a sensitivity list for you based on the logic within the block. Recall that only *inputs* matter in a sensitivity list. Therefore, this always block will be scheduled if `a`, `b`, or `state_reg` change.

In this example, the

```
    y1 = 1'b0;              // default output:  0
    y0 = 1'b0;              // default output:  0
```

is trying to model an *IDLE* state, a state where the FSM is outputting 0. If you do a quick study of how the FSM operates, you'll see that once it starts transitioning through the states, (the case statements) it won't come back out.

Ideally you want your *IDLE* information within a state of its own, not floating outside the state logic, but I suppose this works as a trivial example.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure if it's relevant to your answer, but clk(clock) is an input wire also, so wouldn't it be on the sensitivity list for @* ?  So I was thinking that every time it gets a clock pulse the always block will be evaluated again.  Also since the statements y1 = 1'b0 and y2 = 1'b0 are before the case statement it seems like it would be evaluated.  This is the style the author uses through out the book, where he assigns registers to they're default value at the beginning of NEXT STATE LOGIC always block, usually with a @* sensitivity list.  I could show you other examples?

Comment: @FrankDejay exactly `clk` is an input. However if you look at `always @*` block, clk is never been read (or never used on right hand side of an expression). `@*` in `always @*` includes everything that is been read (RHS) in sensitivity list while compiling/synthesizing so basically even if clk is an input, just because it is never been read in that block it won't affect any of those expressions.

Comment: @wisemonkey  Wow.  I've been misunderstanding this for a long time.  My book seemed to say that @* includes all signals in the module.  I didn't realize it only included signals in the always block.  Make a lot more sense.  Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Hi @FrankDejay, wisemonkey is right. I would also add that you look into how Verilog schedules events. Although Verilog is a programming language, it models hardware, and thus Verilog programs are very different than procedural C programs. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think other answers directly and correctly addresses the question of whether y0 and y1 toggle to 0 and back on every clock cycle.

Let's say that the state machine changes from s0 to s1.  In both states the end value of y1 is 1  but in re-evaluating the always block y1 is first assigned 0.  This toggling may happen multiple times per clock, or not at all on a clock cycle depending how many times a, b, and state_reg change.  Whether this toggling propagates to the wire attached to output y1 is simulator dependent.  Port assignments are treated as continuous assignments in Verilog, which are separately running threads of execution.  It is perfectly legal for the simulator to suspend execution of the always block after the y1=0 assignment is made, assign 0 to the wire attached to output y1, and resume execution of the always block afterwards.  Practically speaking, it doesn't matter IF good coding styles are practiced because the value of y1 won't get latched into any registers until the next clock cycle, long after all the toggling is done and the final value of y1 is available.

In simulation the toggling happens in zero time but it also happens in real hardware when multiple inputs change.  It takes special design practices to build logic that doesn't "glitch" like this.